# "I was happy at my improvement" vs "I was happy with my improvement"

Tags: grammaticality

Are both correct?

If so, what are the differences in meaning if any?

Answer (score 1):

The first version means you *felt happy* **when** you managed to improve something. The second one means you *were satisfied with the results*, having managed to improve it or having done that improvement especially well.

Answer (score -1):

Only “I was happy with my improvement” is grammatically correct.

Similarly, "I was happy about a situation" is correct.

You can't be happy **at** something or someone, just like you cannot be sad **at** something or someone.

The correct usage of **happy at** would be involve a time or place.

**Examples**:

1. I was happy at that time.
2. I was happy at work.

Comment: Hi joe, welcome to EL&U. NB: the system has flagged your post as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide an explanation, preferably backed up by reference to a published source. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Comment: @Chappo 
Thanks for pointing out. I have improved my answer now.

Comment: Joe, this is still inadequate - I think you’re statement that “happy at” is restricted to time or place is simply wrong, and you’ve provided no link to a *published reference* to support your claim - but the question was low quality (which is why it’s on hold) so it may not be worth the effort to improve your answer.